# ORDER BY depending on parameter results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a stored procedure that initiates an order by depending on a parameter:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsersByClusterAndUserName]
  GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsersByClusterAndUserName]
    @SortField [nvarchar] (256) = 'UserName',
    @SortOrder [int] = 0
AS
    SELECT * FROM [User] 
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 0 THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortField = 'UserName' THEN User_UserName 
            WHEN @SortField = 'LastLoginDate' THEN User_LastLoginDate 
            WHEN @SortField = 'CreationDate' THEN User_CreationDate END
    END ASC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN
        CASE
            WHEN @SortField = 'UserName' THEN User_UserName 
            WHEN @SortField = 'LastLoginDate' THEN User_LastLoginDate
            WHEN @SortField = 'CreationDate' THEN [User_CreationDate] END
    END DESC
RETURN 0
GO
```

However... If I call the procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.GetUsersByClusterAndUserName @SortOrder=1, @SortField='UserName'
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUsersByClusterAndUserName, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Why would it try to convert something to date/time. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Good question!  Minor suggestions, make the `@SortOrder` a `BIT`

Comment: Personally, this is something I would make the UI control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably type conversion from the `case`.  When using `order by` in this way, then use multiple `case` statements:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 0 AND @SortField = 'UserName' THEN User_UserName END),
         (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 0 AND @SortField = 'User_LastLoginDate' THEN User_LastLoginDate END),
         (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 0 AND @SortField = 'User_CreationDate' THEN User_CreationDate END),
         (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 1 AND @SortField = 'UserName' THEN User_UserName END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 1 AND @SortField = 'User_LastLoginDate' THEN User_LastLoginDate END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 1 AND @SortField = 'User_CreationDate' THEN User_CreationDate END) DESC
```

The problem is that the `case` has a single output type, determined when the query is compiled.  This type is based on logic combining all the types form the `THEN` clause.  So, the result from each `then` clause is converted to the overall type -- and this is where your error occurs.

You can read about data precedence rules [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).  But the solution is simple: use multiple `case` statements.

Comment: You've got an extra WHEN (the 2nd one) in each CASE statement.